# MySQL 5.7.38 moving average

Tags: mysql, moving-average

I am using an old version of MySQL, so no CTEs and window functions are available.

I am using the following query

```
    SELECT a.order_date,
    a.sales,
    ( SELECT SUM(b.sales) / COUNT(b.sales)
    FROM (SELECT
    date(date_add(t.created_at, interval 4 hour)) as order_date
    ,count(t.barcode)as sales
    from tickets t
    where t.user_id 2 and t.status != 'cancelled'
    group by 1
    ORDER BY order_date
    )AS b
    WHERE DATEDIFF(a.order_date, b.order_date) BETWEEN 0 AND 6
    ) AS '7dayMovingAvg'
    FROM (SELECT
    date(date_add(t.created_at, interval 4 hour)) as order_date
    ,count(t.barcode)as sales
    from tickets t
    where t.user_id <>2 and t.status != 'cancelled'
    group by 1
    ORDER BY order_date
    ) AS a
    ORDER BY a.order_date;
```

The generated data is as follows

| order_date | sales | 7dayMovingAvg |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-09-14 | 20 | 20.0000 |
| 2022-09-15 | 146 | 83.0000 |
| 2022-09-19 | 11 | 59.0000 |
| 2022-09-21 | 5 | 54.0000 |
| 2022-09-22 | 54 | 23.3333 |
| 2022-09-28 | 60 | 57.0000 |
| 2022-09-29 | 174 | 117.0000 |
| 2022-09-30 | 1419 | 551.0000 |
| 2022-10-01 | 439 | 523.0000 |
| 2022-10-02 | 224 | 463.2000 |
| 2022-10-03 | 256 | 428.6667 |
| 2022-10-04 | 232 | 400.5714 |
| 2022-10-05 | 159 | 414.7143 |
| 2022-10-06 | 129 | 408.2857 |
| 2022-10-07 | 148 | 226.7143 |
| 2022-10-08 | 100 | 178.2857 |
| 2022-10-09 | 165 | 169.8571 |
| 2022-10-10 | 93 | 146.5714 |
| 2022-10-11 | 78 | 124.5714 |
| 2022-10-12 | 355 | 152.5714 |
| 2022-10-13 | 95 | 147.7143 |
| 2022-10-14 | 204 | 155.7143 |
| 2022-10-15 | 90 | 154.2857 |
| 2022-10-16 | 120 | 147.8571 |
| 2022-10-17 | 135 | 153.8571 |
| 2022-10-18 | 185 | 169.1429 |
| 2022-10-19 | 185 | 144.8571 |
| 2022-10-20 | 139 | 151.1429 |
| 2022-10-21 | 189 | 149.0000 |
| 2022-10-22 | 107 | 151.4286 |
| 2022-10-23 | 160 | 157.1429 |
| 2022-10-24 | 148 | 159.0000 |
| 2022-10-25 | 170 | 156.8571 |
| 2022-10-26 | 136 | 149.8571 |
| 2022-10-27 | 116 | 146.5714 |
| 2022-10-28 | 189 | 146.5714 |
| 2022-10-29 | 126 | 149.2857 |
| 2022-10-30 | 226 | 158.7143 |
| 2022-10-31 | 245 | 172.5714 |
| 2022-11-01 | 283 | 188.7143 |
| 2022-11-02 | 254 | 205.5714 |
| 2022-11-03 | 276 | 228.4286 |
| 2022-11-04 | 321 | 247.2857 |
| 2022-11-05 | 361 | 280.8571 |
| 2022-11-06 | 347 | 298.1429 |
| 2022-11-07 | 34 | 268.0000 |

> The calculation works fine from 2022-10-04 and thereafter, taking the average of the preceding 7 rows.

> However, the first 6 rows from 2022-09-14 through 2022-09-28 are calculated in a seemingly odd way.

```
|Detail|
|----------|
|Row 1:20  - average of row 1 [1] {20}|
|Row 2:83 - average of rows 1 & 2 [2] {20,146}|
|Row 3:59 - average of rows 1,2,3 [3] {20,146,11}|
|Row 4:54 - average of rows 2,3,4 [3] {146,11,5}|
|Row 5:23 - average of rows 3,4,5 [3] {11,5,54}|
|Row 6:57 - average of rows 5,6 [2] {54,60}|
|Row 7 - average of 2 preceding rows|
|Row 8 - average of 3 preceding rows|
|Row 9 - average of 4 preceding rows|
|Row 10 - average of 5 preceding rows|
|Row 11 - average of 6 preceding rows|
|Row 12 & thereafter - average of 7 preceding rows|
```

I suspect it is because there are some nulls (days without sales) e.g. 16,17,18 Sept are missing?

Is there a workaround given no window functions?

Thanks

Comment: Edit your question, focus on the source data that produces the first 6 rows of avg result where you said "odd". Post that sample data and your expected result.

Comment: Without a Window function MySQL, you're probably better fetching the daily results and doing the moving average in your application code.

Comment: Published code does not syntax what should where t.user_id 2  be?

Comment: So, the question could be reframed as: 'how can I calculate a 7-day moving average, where my data isn't contiguous (has missing days/rows) when I cannot use a CTE or window function'

Comment: If within the 7-day period there are only 4 rows, should the average be calculated `SUM()/4` or should it be calculated as `SUM()/7`?

Comment: @FanoFN SUM()/4